# Apache: After several POSTs content becomes corrupted

Tags: c, apache

If Apache is newly restarted, the first several SUBMITS have no issues.  But after several tests, it begins to print a corrupt version of "v".

```
int main() {
    while (FCGI_Accept() >= 0) {
        printf("Content-Type: text/html;\n\n");

        int content_len;
        content_len = atoi(getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH")); 

        char v[100];
        fread(v,content_len,1,stdin);
        printf("%s",v);

        FCGI_Finish();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: perhaps I need to "free(v);" ? to reset the memory it used or something. Clearly it is getting stored somewhere... and it needs to be emptied.

Perhaps this has something to do with my fcgi settings in httpd.conf ?

Comment: Is `content_len` less than 100?

Comment: it sometimes prints values from the previous submit.

Comment: No, you do not need to free `v`, and in fact you must not do so.  `free()` must be applied only to a pointer to the start of a dynamically-allocated block of memory.

Comment: Also you should and must use `size_t bytes_read = fread(v, 1, content_len, stdin)` and use the value such returned - it is not guaranteed that `fread` returns a nul-terminated string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fread()` doesn't add a null terminator, you need to add that.

```
fread(v,content_len,1,stdin);
v[content_len] = '\0';
```

Otherwise, `printf()` will print the uninitialized characters in the string beyond what was read.

You should also make sure that `v` is big enough to hold the content. Instead of hard-coding the size, you can do:

```
char v[content_len+1];
```

You don't need to `free(v)`, since `free()` can only be used with pointers returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.

Comment: also swap 1, content_len; store the result in a variable and make sure you don't get short reads...